# R S3 class print with plus operator not working as expected

Tags: r

I've defined a S3 class with a print method. However, if I add a number to my S3 object then I do not get the expected result:

```
abc <- function(x, ...) { UseMethod("abc") }
abc.default <- function(x, ...) { structure(as.numeric(x), class="abc", hello=exp(1)) }

print.abc <- function(x, type=c("hello", "numeric"), ...) {
  type <- match.arg(type)
  if (type=="numeric") { ret <- as.numeric(x); print(ret) }
  if (type=="hello") { ret <- attr(x, "hello"); print(ret) }
}

x <- abc(pi)
y <- x+1
y # expected pi+1, not exp(1)
```

If I change the `print` method to

```
print.abc <- function(x, type=c("numeric", "hello"), ...) {
  type <- match.arg(type)
  if (type=="numeric") { ret <- as.numeric(x); print(ret) }
  if (type=="hello") { ret <- attr(x, "hello"); print(ret) }
}
y <- x+1
y # got pi+1
```

then I get the expected result. I suspect that the internal behaviour of `+` leads to this strange results. If this is correct, what happens exactly?

Comment: why are you expecting pi + 1 in the first example?

Comment: Why do you expect that? With the first print definition, `"hello"` will be the default type. As such you get exp(1) (the hello attribute). The second definition of print defaults to numeric, as such prints the numeric attribute.

Comment: the class of `x+1` is `abc` and your first function then follows the logic that @Baraliuh explained, so it will always print `exp(1)` (more specifically `attr(x, 'hello')`). note that `unclass(y)` is pi + 1

Comment: @rawr: ok, I just saw myself that `y` is of class `abc` and I understand the result now. But why is `y` not numeric?

Comment: Id suggest reading Hadley's chapter on `S3` methods (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html), in particular, sub-chapter 6 goes over some of the basics in class inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no underlying magic here; the results are exactly as expected. The behavior of `+` is correct. It is obvious from the following code:

```r
abc <- function(x, ...) { UseMethod("abc") }
abc.default <- function(x, ...) { structure(as.numeric(x), class="abc", hello=exp(1)) }

print.abc <- function(x, type=c("hello", "numeric"), ...) {
  type <- match.arg(type)
  if (type=="numeric") { ret <- as.numeric(x); print(ret) }
  if (type=="hello") { ret <- attr(x, "hello"); print(ret) }
}

x <- abc(pi)
y <- x+1

print(x) # exp(1)
#> [1] 2.718282
print(x, 'hello') # same as print(x); will be exp(1)
#> [1] 2.718282
print(x, 'numeric') # pi
#> [1] 3.141593
y # same as print(y); will be exp(1)
#> [1] 2.718282
print(y, 'numeric') # pi + 1
#> [1] 4.141593
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The only issue is that you do not properly define the default `type` argument in the `print` method. Note that `print` is always called for `stdout`. As such, for the S3 class `abc` `print.abc` will be called (with default settings) when you print an `abc` class.